# How to create tabs within pagination like the cricbuzz site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I am trying to create a page for cricket Rankings for Test, ODI and t20 like cricbuzz in ASP.Net MVC. I need to create pagination and tabs combined such that the first one must consist of Test, ODI and t20 whereas the second must consist of Batsmen, Bowlers and Team Rankings and I have to link the tabs and pagination accordingly.

[image: Sample Image]

The code is

```
  <h2><b><i>Ranking</i></b></h2>
<br>

<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#teams">Teams</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#batsmen">Batsmen</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#bowlers">Bowlers</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#allrounders">All rounders</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<ul id="paginationId" class="pagination">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#test">Test</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#odi">ODI</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#t20">T20</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="test" class="tab-pane fade in active">@Html.Action("TeamTestRanking")</div>
    <div id="odi" class="tab-pane fade in">@Html.Action("TeamODIRanking")</div>
    <div id="t20" class="tab-pane fade in">@Html.Action("Teamt20Ranking")</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You say pagination, but it looks like you are using tabs... 2 very different things. It looks like you are talking about nested tabs?

Comment: @VDWWD Yes I'm trying to achieve the result either way using tabs or pagination. But not getting it quite right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want "sub" tabs, then make nested tab pages and controls. See the example below.

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#teams">Teams</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#batsmen">Batsmen</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#bowlers">Bowlers</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#allrounders">All rounders</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">

    <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="teams" role="tabpanel">

        <ul id="paginationId1" class="pagination">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#test_1">Test</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#odi_1">ODI</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#t20_1">T20</a></li>
        </ul>

        <h1>Teams</h1>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="test_1" role="tabpanel">
                    <h2>Test Teams</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="odi_1" role="tabpanel">
                    <h2>ODI Teams</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="t20_1" role="tabpanel">
                    <h2>T20 Teams</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="batsmen" role="tabpanel">

        <ul id="paginationId2" class="pagination">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#test_2">Test</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#odi_2">ODI</a></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#t20_2">T20</a></li>
        </ul>

        <h1>Batsmen</h1>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade active show" id="test_2" role="tabpanel">
                    <h2>Test Batsmen</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="odi_2" role="tabpanel">
                    <h2>ODI Batsmen</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="t20_2" role="tabpanel">
                    <h2>T20 Batsmen</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="bowlers" role="tabpanel">
        <h1>Bowlers</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="allrounders" role="tabpanel">
        <h1>All rounders</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```